# Kerberos AES-256 encryption not working on Linux

Tags: linux, encryption, active-directory, aes, kerberos

I am trying to create AES-256 encrypted Kerberos token from Linux servers (server is not domain joined). I am using a keytab which I have generated using Kinit command. When I use RC4-HMAC TGT and TGS both tickets are generated properly. But with AES-256, after a struggle, even if I am able to generate TGT ticket, TGS ticket generation is still failing.

I have checked AES-256 and AES-128 both are added to my profile in Active Directory. As this solution had [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43674331/kerberos-aes-256-encryption-not-working) .

Below are my commands -

### krb5.conf is setup to support only AES-256

```
default_tkt_enctypes = aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96
default_tgs_enctypes = aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96
```

### Generate Keytab with ktutil

1. `add_entry -password -p <my UPN>@<MY DOMAIN IN CAPS> -k 1 -e aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96`
2. Print the salt, by `list -e` command
3. `add_entry -key -p <my SAMAccountName>@<MY DOMAIN IN CAPS> -k 1 -e aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96`
4. Enter the salt
5. `write_kt <keytab name>`

> Matching the salt is important, since ktutil algorithm is different
>   from Active Directory. Suggested solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49282283/kerberos-aes-256-keytab-does-not-work)

### Generate TGT ticket

`kinit -kt <my keytab> <my SAMAccountName>@<MY DOMAIN IN CAPS> -c krb5cache`

### Generate TGS Ticket

`env KRB5_CONFIG=krb5.conf KRB5_TRACE=/dev/stdout KRB5CCNAME=krb5cache kvno HTTP/my.website.com`

> That's where it fails with "KDC has no support for encryption type" error.

`kvno: KDC has no support for encryption type while getting credentials for HTTP/my.website.com@[MY DOMAIN IN CAPS]`